# GridView fixed header CSS alignment

Tags: asp.net, css, gridview

I'm trying to get a GridView CSS solution for fixed headers to work, but the only way I can get the header row to line up with the rest of the columns is to use position:relative, but then that breaks the fixed header that I'm trying to achieve.  The top adjustment seems out of whack, and the "cells" of the header seem to be all mushed together.

My CSS:

```
.fixedHeader
{
   font-weight:bold;
   font-size:small;
   position:absolute;
   width:1070px;
   text-align:justify;
   background-color: #006699;
   color: #ffffff;
   height: 25px;
   expression(Sys.UI.DomElement.getBounds(document.getElementById("Panel3")).y-      25);
}
```

My GridView:

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel3" runat="server" Height="354px" ScrollBars="Vertical" 
        Width="1070px" Font-Size="Small" onscroll="$get('MainContent_hdnScrollTop').value = this.scrollTop;">

          <input type="hidden" id="hdnScrollTop" runat="server" value="0" />

        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"  
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowSorting="True" CellPadding="4" 
        ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" 
        onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                <HeaderStyle CssClass="fixedHeader" />
```

[image: The header smooshed]

Comment: Hi, There will be lot of issues if you are trying to use this css method. I am using a third party gridview control for this. It is just an extension of asp.net grid view.  http://ideasparks.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

Would you be able to wrap your header in another DIV that has position:absolute; on it, then use the working position:relative; CSS to get it to align with your other content?

It's hard to say without being able to see what the alignment issues are.

Comment: I added the image.  As you can see the top position is off, and the header row is smooshed together, and doesn't respect the cell spacing.